# How to create a directory named '-p' under Linux with Bash?

Tags: linux, bash

In Bash, how could I create a directory named `-p`?

`mkdir -p` failed.
`mkdir "-p"` failed.
`mkdir "\-p"` failed.
`mkdir \-p` failed.

Comment: Note that all of these are attempting to escape the parameter for bash. Since it's the same escaped as not escaped, all of these except the third will just send the string "-p" to mkdir, which will parse it as an option. The option parsing isn't done in bash, so any way around this (described in the answers below) is a feature of mkdir (or rather, a lack of bug).

Comment: Gotta ask why you'd want such a directory.  It would be a PITA to use.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: I  created this folder by mistake, but do not know how to delete it.

Comment: Shouldn't, then, the question be "How to delete a directory named '-p' under Linux with Bash"?

Comment: @chepner: Because they are same problems actually. I tried to delete the directory with `rmdir` but failed with same errors.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Most utilities (all POSIX compliant ones except for `test` and `echo`) support an ["end of options" option](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/dict/terms/end_of_options) `--`, so you could run:

```
mkdir -- -p
```

This is especially useful when renaming or removing files that could potentially start with a dash. In scripts you should always use

```
mv -- "$filename"
```

instead of a plain `mv "$filename"` or, even worse, an unquoted filename.

Comment: Awesome. This is really good to know

Answer (score 18):

`mkdir ./-p`

Keep in mind that most other programs would need to use the same "trick".